# How to make the windows material transparent so that I can see an image through it?

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, transparency, glass

I created a room (floor, table, walls and windows). For the windows' faces, I used a material with the following features (I list below only the features I changed, the remaining ones kept standard, ie, as they came):

- Principled BSDF
- Base color: white
- Specular: 0.15
- Roughness: 0
- IOR: 1.5
- Transmission: 1
- Emission strenght: 0

I checked **Screen Space Reflection** both in materials and in Eevee render.

Finally, I added a reference image with sky and trees to be the outside environment. However, I cannot see the image through the windows (either in material or render mode, independently of rendering in eevee or cycles).

My question is: **How to make the windows material transparent so that I can see an image through it?**

Comment: Wooow. That works! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using transparency in EEVEE, make sure to set the material's Blend Mode to something other than *Opaque*. Alpha-Blend or Alpha Hashed should work fine. For some objects, you may also find things look better if you also enable *Backface Culling*:

[image: Trans]